# How to create new client certificates / tokens for programmatic access to the Kubernetes API hosted on GKE?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running a Kubernetes cluster hosted on GKE and would like to write an application (written in Go) that speaks to the Kubernetes API. My understanding is that I can either provide a client certificate, bearer token, or HTTP Basic Authentication in order to authenticate with the apiserver. I have already found the right spot to inject any of these into the [Golang client library](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.1/pkg/client/).

Unfortunately, the examples I ran across tend to reference to existing credentials stored in my personal kubeconfig file. This seems non-advisable from a security perspective and makes me believe that I should create a new client certificate / token / username-password pair in order to support easy revocation/removal of compromised accounts. However, I could not find a spot in the documentation actually describing how to go about this when running on managed Kubernetes in GKE. (There's [this guide on creating new certificates](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/) explaining that the apiserver needs to get restarted with updated parameters eventually, something that to my understanding cannot be done in GKE.)

Are my security concerns for reusing my personal Kubernetes credentials in one (or potentially multiple) applications unjustified? If not, what's the right approach to generate a new set of credentials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is running inside the cluster, you can use [Kubernetes Service Accounts](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/) to authenticate to the API server.

If this is outside of the cluster, things aren't as easy, and I suppose your concerns are justified. Right now, GKE does not allow additional custom identities beyond the one generated for your personal kubeconfig file.

Instead of using your credentials, you could grab a service account's token (inside a pod, read from `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`), and use that instead. It's a gross hack, and not a great general solution, but it might be slightly preferable to using your own personal credentials.

Comment: My application does run outside of the cluster. The service account hack should be acceptable for me as I don't plan on running too many off-cluster apps.

Comment: Does the service account's token expire at some point though? Is it possibly bound to the lifetime of the pod? That'd be a show-stopper for me.

Comment: You can manually expire the service account token by deleting the secret object.  A new one will be created.  Pods that use the deleted token will need to be restarted.